# How do I set the correct json headers?

Tags: json, header, getjson

Is there a way in htaccess to ensure the headers for my json are correct?

Update: Does anyone see anything wrong with these headers for json?

```
Date    Mon, 26 Jul 2010 08:31:11 GMT
Server  Apache/2.2.15 (Unix) mod_ssl/2.2.15 OpenSSL/0.9.7a mod_fcgid/2.3.5 Phusion_Passenger/2.2.15 mod_auth_passthrough/2.1 mod_bwlimited/1.4 FrontPage/5.0.2.2635
X-Powered-By    PHP/5.2.13
X-Pingback  http://brettbarros.com/wordpress/xmlrpc.php
Content-Disposition attachment; filename="json_api.json"
Vary    Accept-Encoding
Content-Encoding    gzip
Content-Length  719
Keep-Alive  timeout=5, max=98
Connection  Keep-Alive
Content-Type    application/json; charset=UTF-8
```

Specifically, it's working with jquery's getJSON in ie8, ffx, chrome, but not ie7 or ie6...

Comment: What do you use to create the JSON responses? Or are they stored as files?

Comment: wordpress plugin called json-api

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can inspect the headers sent along from the server side using [Firebug's](http://getfirebug.com) Net tab. It shows all the headers for both the request and the response.

Answer (score 26):

```
AddType application/json .json
```

is a simple way to make all your `*.json` files being sent with the correct mime type. That, of course, doesn't work, if you create them dynamically in something like a, say, PHP script. In that case, you can add the info inside the script:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: application/json');
// ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the Content-Type is `application/json`. You can inspect the http headers with wget and whatnot if you aren't sure what they are.