# Jquery Ajax Request working on Ubuntu but not working on Debian?

Tags: jquery, ajax, debian

I have a strange bug.

I develop my application under linux ubuntu.

Then i export my project under linux debian for production.

I use a **classic** `$.ajax` request which return to `url` ,a `json` file to parse its content.

I created a javascript `alert()` on the `sucess` part to see what is returned.

Under the developpement version under ubuntu, it's works and i get :

```
 [object Object],[object Object],[object Object]
```

Under the **production environnement** under **debian**, it's not working and i get my jsonfile content :

```
    [
   {
      "cell_line" : "",
      "id_user" : "2",
      "public" : "0",

   },{...},{..} ,etc...]
```

What is going on here?
I really don't understand?

How the change of platform (ubuntu to debian) can do this???

There is something I am missing..

I'll really appreciate some help on that. Thanks!

**Update :**

I'm doing something like that

var first_ajax_call = $.ajax({url:'path_to_data/data.json',success:function(obj){ 
       alert(obj); }});

Comment: Possibly your production server isn't set up to serve JSON files correctly. Talk to the webmaster.

Comment: Your JSON probably gets delivered with an incorrect MIME type. Please check (and post here) the HTTP headers that are sent with the response. See this related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3333196/how-do-i-set-the-correct-json-headers

Comment: What's the server ? Is it simply apache serving static json files ? (if so check mime types).

Comment: I found ! [link](http://josh.gourneau.com/blog/2010/11/16/serve-json-as-content-type-applicationjson-with-apache-on-ubuntu/

Answer (score 0):

You should start your php like this:

```
<?php
header('Content-type: application/json');
// then output the json encoded object
```